# Qt Stylesheet management and performances

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet

I have an issue with the management of Qt style sheets.

I have a big Qt application that can change its colors theme dynamically. To do that, I created several style sheets (one by theme - they are quite big). When a user wants to change the color theme, he clicks on a button that calls the `QWidget` method `setStylesheet(QString)`  of the `MainWindow`. This actually works but my GUI freezes 8-10 seconds in the process.

To reduce the delay, I've tried to use `unpolish(QApplication * application)` and `QStyle::polish(QApplication * application)`. The performance is quite impressive (less than one second) but several `Widget` properties are not updated, e.g. the icon property of the `QToolButton`. Moreover all my custom widgets are not updated even if they inherits from common widget classes (`QFrame`, `Qwidget`, `QStackedWidget` etc...).
Do I miss something with the `polish` method? Is there another way to perform a better update of the style of my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setPalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setPalette)(  [QPalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html) )

```
void QApplication::setPalette ( const QPalette & palette, const char * className = 0 ) [static]
```

> Changes the default application palette to palette.
>
> The palette may be changed according to the current GUI style in
>   QStyle::polish().
>
> Warning: Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets.
>   When using style sheets, the palette of a widget can be customized
>   using the "color", "background-color", "selection-color",
>   "selection-background-color" and "alternate-background-color".
>
> Note: Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for
>   instance, if they make use of native theme engines.

If you want to change theme of all widgets from one place, this is good way.
I use this in big application and it's working good.

But if you set styleSheet or palette to a widget, it is not getting your general theme.

```
QPalette myPalette;
myPalette.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::red);
myPalette.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(150, 150, 150));
qApp->setPalette(myPalette);
```

Comment: Yes, but this represents to much work. I am stuck with css files and I must use them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlJah : You are right, when i switch from stylSheet to `QPalette`, it take more than one week from me .
your welcome.