# Qt StyleSheet system is invalidating QPalette; how to make them work together?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, palette

I have in one of my projects a QwtPlot where I want to configure its colors in an harmonious way - that is, e.g., if the background color is white, the axis should be black, etc.. Now I could do this in a "hardcoded way": each time the background color (the reference) is changed, I look at an array of previously defined colors for the axis and set the given color in the array for that axis. But this is quite "out of fashion" and I would like a more automated way.

Seeking help [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/61024-Changing-the-font-size-and-the-color-of-QwtPlot-scale-labels), Uwe told me to use `QwtPlot::setPalette(color)`, and it works great *by itself*. The problem is that the QwtPlot is child of a series of QWidget-based widgets whose colors should be configured in a global style sheet file and I noticed that when the style sheet for one of those widgets is configured, it invalidates the QwtPlot's call to `setPalette`. It is as if I should choose between them: if I'm going to use at least one call to `setPalette` in a given widget, then none of its parents up to the main widget (a QMainWindow in my case) should be configured with the style sheet system. This seems what this part of the documentation about `setPalette` is saying:

> Warning: Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets.([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272493/qt-stylesheet-management-and-performances/27276342#27276342))

, but it would seem that was supposed to be the case only when using a global call to `setPalette`.

So my questions are: is there a way to solve this problem in an harmonious way? Or do I need to abandon the style sheet system for that part of the software and use just palettes instead? I tried to make the style sheet configuration in a more "localized" way - that is trying to say to the system "this stylesheet configuration is only valid for this widget; don't perpetuate it to its child widgets", with no success. If this is really possible (and therefore I probably chosed the wrong syntax), I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

In your style sheet, use `.QWidget {...}` rather than `QWidget {...}` for styles that you don't want subclasses to inherit. If applied to all the `QwtPlot`parents this will allow you to use `setPalette` again.

Nothing can save you however if you try to mix style sheets and palettes for the same widget, the style sheet will always supersede it, so beware!

EDIT:

another option is to subclass `QwtPlot` and use designable properties for the canvas, allowing you to use style sheets to set the property, but also have programmatic access to the value.

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBrush>    
#include <qwt_plot.h>

class QPlot : public QwtPlot
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QBrush canvasBackground READ canvasBackground 
        WRITE setCanvasBackground DESIGNABLE true)

public:

    QPlot(const QwtText &title, QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QwtPlot(title, parent);

    void setCanvasBackground(const QBrush &brush) 
    { 
        QwtPlot::setCanvasBackground(brush); 
        // set the axes color as well, maybe YIQ method?
    };
    QBrush canvasBackground() const
    {
         return QwtPlot::canvasBackground;
    }
};
```

In your style sheet you could then set the canvas background with

```
qproperty-canvasBackground: #000000;
```

The contrasting color algorithm I think is a bit out of scope for this answer, but these questions may help: [Programmatically choose high-contrast colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407793/programmatically-choose-high-contrast-colors), [How do I invert a colour / color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour-color-c-net)

Comment: it doesn't seems that it works, Nicolas =T I just discovered that if I put anything - even things not related to my QwtPlot's parent widgets - in the global stylesheet, then any usage of setPalette for QwtPlot or any of its parent widgets is invalidated. I put, for example, a style sheet configuration for QLabels in the global stylesheet file and I even called `setStyleSheet("");` in my QwtPlot parent Widget and even so the call to `setPalette` was invalidated =T Any suggestions?

Comment: @Momergil My honest advice is don't use palettes. The feature isn't well supported. If you have to choose between palettes and style sheets, I'd personally always choose style sheets. In the past I've subclassed `QwtPlot` and set the DESIGNABLE true flag on the canvasBackground property, which allows you to set it from the style sheet but also read and write it programmatically. Then, I'd overwrite the setCanvasBackground setter function to choose a high-contrast color for the axes based on the rgb or hsv of the canvas brush.